# Add a new user in a table row using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular admin project, in this project the user can add/delete users in the data base. I have a list of all users showing at the same page as are the delete button and the add new user fields; so, when I delete/add I want this new user to show immediately at the screen or to vanish of the screen (in the case of delete).

Here is my controller of the add user:

```
(function(){
    angular.module("agendaRaiar").controller('findUserController', ['$scope','UserWsService', function($scope, UserWsService){
        $scope.passTheScope = function(user){
            $scope.objectUser = user; //isso é feito para ter o id dentro do deletecontroller
        }

        $scope.getUsersAtParse = function(){
                UserWsService.getUsersAtParse().then(function(resultArray) {
                    $scope.users = resultArray;
                    console.log(resultArray);
                });
        };
    }]);
}());
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `$scope.user.push(resultArray)?` this will add the newly created user in your view. for delete, try on `$scope.user.splice`

```
 $http.post(...).then(function(response){
  $scope.myarrayObj.push(response);
});
```